# AWS IAM Policy Resource specification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

While creating a policy and testing it in AWS Policy simulator, the Policy#1 works fine but Policy#2 doesn't. The only difference being how the Resource attribute is written

Policy#1

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": ["lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "lambda:InvokeAsync"],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:::*"
    }]
}
```

Policy#2

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": ["lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "lambda:InvokeAsync"],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:::*"
    }]
}
```

In Policy simulator on AWS, I selected 2 function simulation as mentioned in the action section of policies above.
AWS policy simulator passes the Policy#1 where as Policy #2 fails and AWS complaints on not finding a matching statement in the policy file.

My interpretation of the line `"Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:::*"` is that it implicitly identifies all lambda resources in my current aws account in my region.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Both of your policies are identical. Your question on the other hand seems to indicate that there should be a difference. Can you clarify that?

Comment: @jenswalter I have updated the question with some more clarifications. Yes, I understand. Both policies look the same to me. But why would AWS policy simulator pass #1 but fail #2?